# Python plotly dash - button to link to webpage

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using python dash and I'd like to have a button below my table that when clicked, will take the user to a specific webpage. I am very - VERY - new to using dash so I'm not even sure if this functionality exists. I did search this topic specifically to python dash and came up empty handed. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ## use this for button example and to learn more please use this
>
> link:https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(dcc.Input(id='input-box', type='text')),
    html.Button('Submit', id='button'),
    html.Div(id='output-container-button',
             children='Enter a value and press submit')
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container-button', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('button', 'n_clicks')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('input-box', 'value')])
def update_output(n_clicks, value):
    return 'The input value was "{}" and the button has been clicked {} times'.format(
        value,
        n_clicks
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *dash_bootstrap_components* or dbc to do that. Check this page for more detailed information about dbc: https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/button/

To summarize, what you need to do:

1. If you haven't done yet, pip install dbc:
   `pip install dash-bootstrap-components`
2. Import it to your code:
   `import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc`
3. Configure your app with one of the dbc themes. When you creat the app, just include an external_stylesheet:

   `app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CYBORG])`
4. Include the dbc.Button componen in your app (see examples in documentation or below).

Here is an example:

```
from dash import Dash, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CYBORG])

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div("Default format"),
    dbc.Button(
    children='Open Page', 
    id='button_plain',
    href = "https://stackoverflow.com/"),
html.Br(),
html.Br(),
html.Br(),
html.Div("Modify format"),
dbc.Button(
    children='Open Page', 
    id='button_format',
    color = "primary",
    outline = True, #more lightweight format
    size = "lg", #sm, lg
    href = "https://stackoverflow.com/"),

])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

More about dbc Themes: https://bootswatch.com/